# Jenkins Maven OWASP error "[ERROR] IO Exception connecting to https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2008.xml.gz"

Tags: maven, sonarqube, maven-plugin, owasp

we're facing following error while analizing code with OWASP

```
14:23:39 [ERROR] IO Exception connecting to https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2008.xml.gz: HEAD request returned a non-200 status code: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2008.xml.gz
14:23:39 [ERROR] IO Exception connecting to https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2002.xml.gz: HEAD request returned a non-200 status code: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2002.xml.gz
14:23:39 [ERROR] IO Exception connecting to https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2018.xml.gz: HEAD request returned a non-200 status code: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2018.xml.gz
14:23:39 [ERROR] IO Exception connecting to https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2009.xml.gz: HEAD request returned a non-200 status code: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2009.xml.gz
14:23:39 [ERROR] IO Exception connecting to https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2007.xml.gz: HEAD request returned a non-200 status code: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2007.xml.gz
14:23:39 [WARNING] Unable to download the NVD CVE data; the results may not include the most recent CPE/CVEs from the NVD.
14:23:39 [INFO] If you are behind a proxy you may need to configure dependency-check to use the proxy.
14:23:39 [ERROR] IO Exception connecting to https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2010.xml.gz: HEAD request returned a non-200 status code: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/2.0/nvdcve-2.0-2010.xml.gz
14:23:39 [WARNING] Unable to update Cached Web DataSource, using local data instead. Results may not include recent vulnerabilities.
14:23:39 [ERROR] No documents exist
14:23:39 
14:23:39 Unable to continue dependency-check analysis.
14:23:39 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:23:39 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
14:23:39 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
14:23:40 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
14:23:40 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:4.0.2:check (default-cli) on project wbe-common: Fatal exception(s) analyzing wbe-common: Unable to continue dependency-check analysis.
14:23:40 [ERROR] Unable to download the NVD CVE data.
14:23:40 [ERROR] No documents exist
...
14:23:40 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
14:23:40 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
14:23:40 Finished: FAILURE
```

and we're using "3.1.2" version in POM file, but still no luck

```
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <cveUrl12Modified>https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cve/1.2/nvdcve-modified.xml.gz</cveUrl12Modified>
...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Can someone plz help on this.

~Karthik

Comment: First the version you are using is very old (https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.owasp/dependency-check-maven) ... second that looks like a network issue... but I would suggest to upgrade first...And no you are not using version 3.1.2 because the output shows 4.0.2 instead...

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response, in pom I've update version to 6.0.2, 

  `<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId> 
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2</version>
</plugin>`
but still getting same error as below

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:4.0.2:check (default-cli) on project wbe-common: Fatal exception(s) analyzing wbe-common: Unable to continue dependency-check analysis.
14:23:40 [ERROR] Unable to download the NVD CVE data`

Comment: Obviously you have not updated because: `goal org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:4.0.2` and not 6.X ...

Comment: I've updated with 5.1.1, Now I'm getting only one error
`15:24:39 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:5.1.1:check (default) on project wbe-common: Fatal exception(s) analyzing wbe-common: One or more exceptions occurred during analysis:
15:24:39 [ERROR] Unable to download meta file: https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.0/nvdcve-1.0-modified.meta; received 404 -- resource not found
15:24:39 [ERROR] No documents exist
15:24:39 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]`

Comment: Remove the manually added entry from your configuration...

Comment: I've removed those entries and still getting same error
                 `<plugin>
    <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
    <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</plugin>`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version of org.owasp plugin in pom.xml from 4.0.2 to 5.3.1 updated in 10-mar-2020 in Maven Central Repository, to following recomendation of khmarbaise and it worked.